# anchor tag scrolls to top after onclick event return false doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event that will not return false after I have called my ajax function i was wondering how I can get around this. I have used e.preventDefault() which works so that the url doesn't add a hash but when I use return false after my ajax function it doens't work but If I do it the other way round it works but cancels out my ajax call.

```
<a href="#">Click me</a>

$('a').click(function(e) {
    getProducts(..., ...., ....) //my ajax function
    e.preventDefault() // doesn't work
    return false; doesn't work either
});
```

Comment: a few thoughts here. #1 e.preventDefault() only works if you pass in the event via function(e) {...} you aren't which would be a problem.  #2 From what you've described the only thing I can suggest is that you've got a javascript error which leads to thought #3...If you want more help you're going to have to give us more to go on.

Comment: Yeah there is an error in my other script for my menu which is conflicting with it.

Comment: I'll post this as an answer.  If you need more assistance you can post your JS and I'm sure someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cancel the default action using `preventDefault` function.

```
$('a').click(function(e) { 
    getProducts(..., ...., ....) //my ajax function
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: I've just disabled my menu system and now it works so there must be something conflicting with my script. I wonder what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

a few thoughts here. #1 e.preventDefault() only works if you pass in the event via function(e) {...} you aren't which would be a problem. #2 From what you've described the only thing I can suggest is that you've got a javascript error which leads to thought #3...If you want more help you're going to have to give us more to go on